# On the sequences of the form $a^n+b$ which are composite for every $n \in \mathbb N$ and are such that we have $GCD(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have asked some questions before on the sequences of this form but now I would like to collect as many as possible examples of the sequences of the form $a^n+b$ such that we have $GCD(a,b)=1$ and that every member of the sequence is a composite number.

I do not need the proof of compositeness of a particular sequence or of some maybe general class of sequences, I need just that you give me an example or examples of sequences for which you know that it is always composite.

This question is motivated by the need for understanding the structure of such sequences and why for some it is known that they are always composite and for some it is not known.

Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try $a$ and $b$ both odd, positive, coprime and not both $1$.

(As requested in comment).  A similar case: $a=3k+1, b=6j-1$ if coprime; produces results all divisible by $3$

Comment: Okay, that would give even numbers for every $n$, but I am after some more exotic examples.

Comment: Such that one number is odd and the other is even.

Comment: Okay: $a=6k-2, b=6j-1$

Comment: You can write that example in the answer. I would like to see it there.

Comment: Can we in a similar fashion produce sequences such that every member is divisible by some prime number $p$, just like you produced for $3$?

Comment: $a=pk+1$ and $b=2pj-1$?

Comment: @AntePaladin: Yes - so long as $a$ and $b$ are coprime.